# Some calculations about divergence of vector field on Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume first that we have a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Furthermore, $X$ is a vector field on M and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection as usual. Let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis on M.

Then how can we get $\operatorname{div} X =\sum_i\langle e_i,\nabla_{e_i}X\rangle$? Where $\operatorname{div} $ represents the divergence of $X$. In other words, $\operatorname{div} X=\operatorname{tr}(\nabla X)$.

I try to use the definition of covariant differential and we have
$$\operatorname{div} X = \sum_{i}\nabla X(e_i,e_i)=\sum_{i}\nabla_{e_i}X(e_i)$$ but what’s next? I have found many books and they just ignore the detail so can someone help me ? Many thanks to you.

Comment: Firstly, requiring $e_i$ be an orthonormal basis is the wrong condition. You should instead require it to be a *coordinate* basis. If you don't know the difference, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797693/coordinate-and-non-coordinate-basis-orthonormality-and-orthogonality).

Comment: Second, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here. Typically $\operatorname{div}=\operatorname{tr}\nabla$ is taken as a *definition*, not something that you are supposed to show.

Comment: @K.defaoite I usually define the divergence of a vector field $X$ to be the unique smooth function such that $L_X \mathrm{d}vol_g = (\mathrm{div} X) \mathrm{d}vol_g$ ($M$ should be orientable), and it makes sense trying to show the equality $\mathrm{div}X = \mathrm{tr} \nabla X$. Moreover, it totally makes sense to work with an orthonormal frame $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ since the definition is tensorial. No need to consider coordinate basis. In fact, it is the good condition since the trace of an endomorphism $A$ is given by $\sum_i \langle Ae_i,e_i\rangle$ only in an orthonormal basis

Comment: @OP What is your definition of divergence? What do you mean by $\nabla X(e_i,e_i)$?

Comment: @K.defaoite I want to prove how the divergence of a vector field X can be $\sum_i\langle e_i, \nabla_{e_i} X\rangle$. And I think i can just take an orthonormal frame $\{e_1,…, e_n\}$ as Didier said.

Comment: @Didier I know the definition of divergence you mentioned. The two definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$

We consider the following definition of the divergence. Let $(M,g)$ be an orientable Riemannian manifold, with Riemannian volume form $\mathrm{d}vol_g$, and $X$ be a vector field. The divergence of $X$ is the unique smooth function $\div X$ such that $L_X\mathrm{d}vol_g = (\div X) \mathrm{d}vol_g$.

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a local orthonormal frame and consider its dual frame $\{\theta^1,\ldots,\theta^n\}$, that is $\theta^i = g(\cdot,e_i)$. Then we have the equality
$$
\mathrm{d}vol_g = \theta^1\wedge\cdots\wedge \theta^n.
$$
Indeed, these two volume forms are proportional and coincide on the orthonormal frame $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Now, since $L_X$ is a derivation of the exterior algebra, it follows that
$$
L_X\mathrm{d}vol_g = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^1\wedge\cdots\wedge L_X\theta^i \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n.
$$
For any vector field $Y$, we have
\begin{align}
(L_X\theta^i)(Y) &= X\theta^i(Y) - \theta^i([X,Y]) & \text{by Leibniz rule}\\
&= Xg(Y,e_i) - g([X,Y],e_i)\\
&= g(\nabla_XY-[X,Y],e_i) + g(Y,\nabla_Xe_i) &\text{from the compatibility of $g$ and $\nabla$}\\
&= g(\nabla_YX,e_i) + g(Y,\nabla_Xe_i) & \text{since $\nabla$ is torsion-free}\\
&= (\theta^i\circ \nabla X)(Y) + g(Y,\nabla_Xe_i).
\end{align}
Applying $\nabla_X$ to the equality $\|e_i\|^2 = 1$ gives $\nabla_Xe_i\perp e_i$, so that the 1-form $g(\cdot,\nabla_Xe_i)$ vanishes on $e_i$, and is then a linear combination of $\{\theta^j\}_{j\neq i}$. It then disappears in the wedge product, and it follows that
$$
L_X\mathrm{d}vol_g = \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^1\wedge\cdots\wedge (\theta^i\circ \nabla X) \wedge \cdots \wedge \theta^n.
$$
Finally, evaluating on the orthonormal frame $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ yields
\begin{align}
\div X &= \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^1(e_1)\times \cdots \times \theta^i(\nabla_{e_i}X) \times \cdots \theta^n(e_n)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \theta^i(\nabla_{e_i}X)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n g(\nabla_{e_i}X,e_i)\\
&= \tr \nabla X.
\end{align}

There are plenty of other proofs (on this website also) relying on the coordinate expression of the Riemannian volume form. This method is known as the method of *moving frames* (referring to the local orthonormal (co-)frame). It surprisingly turns out that it is less known whilst it is (in my opinion) simpler. Some people (including me) prefer to work in a coordinate-free manner, and to that end, moving frames are good friends.

Comment: An elegant proof！Thanks a lot.